# Bootstrap grid in xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap grid as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"> Column A </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"> Column B </div>
</div>
```

Which obviously shows Column A on the left and Column B on the right.When move to smaller screens it will be A on top and B below.

Is there a way to keep A on the left and B on the right on larger screens, but let B be on top and A below on small screens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap [Push and Pull](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/pushpull-columns-for-only-smaller-screen-sizes-in-bootstrap-3/).

```css
body,
html {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants on `xs` not in `md`

Comment: That doesn't actually make sense as xs will not stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs"> Column A </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"> Column B </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md"> Column A </div>
</div>
```

you can add a duplicate column from A after B.
Hide the first A when the screen is sm or xs.
And hide the second A when screen is lg or md.